# VB6: How do I connect to SQL server without the service manager installed on the client?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I am creating an application in Visual Basic 6.0 which has SQL server as its database. I want to  connect to the database without having MS SQL service manager installed on the client. How can this be done? Should i add any dll's or .tbl or .ocx files?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to connect to the server. If you look at the control panel on the clients computer, does it have an applet called ODBC in there? (Might also be in the Admin Tools folder instead of straight in the control panle).

If so, try creating a link to the SQL Server DB, and if that works you might not need anything else. If that's missing you might need to install [MDAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components) to get the correct drivers on there.

After that it is just to write your normal code in VB6 (probably using ADO).

Comment: No it does not have an applet called ODBC

Comment: @user: Then install a suitable version of MDAC and one should appear.

Comment: i have installed suitable version of MDAC but still i am getting an error telling sql server does not exist or access denied in this line "dbcon.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=maram20;Initial Catalog=haidata;User ID=sa;Password=;"

Comment: Validate you connection string properties first. Once you have MDAC installed you should be able to choose a provider when creating a connection to a database with the ODBC Manager.

Open your Data Source (ODBC) manager by either going here:
Control Panel >> Administration Tools >> Data Sources (ODBC) or type `odbcad32` into your windows run prompt (Start >> Run...).

Create a ODBC connection in the manager, selecting on of the installed SQL Drivers.
Fill in the blanks and keep clicking the `Next` button.
At the last dialog you see a button `Test Data Source...`.

Comment: Fix any issues here until you are able to connect. Once able to connect, use the correct properties / credentials in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Q = "Select contact, company, phone, address, city, state, zip from contacts"

'create db objects
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection       'Database Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset          'RecordSet
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=" & LCase(sSQL_Password) & ";User ID=" & sSQL_USER & ";Data Source=" & sSQL_Server & "; Initial Catalog=" & sSQL_DB & ";connect timeout=10"
conn.CommandTimeout = 20

'open connnection
rs.Open Q, conn, , adCmdText

While Not rs.EOF
    vTotalMail = rs.Fields("TheNumber").Value
    gridResults.AddItem ("Contact" & vbTab & "Companyt" & vbTab & "phone" & vbTab & "address" & vbTab & "City" & vbTab & "State" & vbTab & "Zip" & vbTab)
    rs2.MoveNext
Wend

rs.Close
```

be sure your SQL server name is correct (and not an INSTANCE like servername\instance or something.)